Keras tuner with functional model, incorrect results
I'm trying to use the Keras Tuner package to do a hyperparameter search, including tuning the number of layers in my NN.
My code looks as follows:
def model_builder(hp):

    inputs = Input(shape=(40,6))
    
    x = inputs
    
    for i in range(hp.Int('num_LSTM_layers',1,3)):
        print("l:",i)
        x = LSTM(hp.Int('lstm' + str(i) + '_units',
                        min_value=32,
                        max_value=256,
                        step=16),
                 return_sequences=True)(x)

    for j in range(hp.Int('num_dense_layers',1,4)):
        print("d:",j)
        x = Dense(hp.Int('dense' + str(j) + '_units',
                         min_value=16,
                         max_value=128,
                         step=16),
                         activation=hp.Choice("dense" + str(j) + "_activation", ["relu", "selu","leaky_relu","tanh"]))(x)

    output1 = Dense(1,activation='relu',name="WhiteElo")(x)
    output2 = Dense(1,activation='relu',name="BlackElo")(x)

    hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-3, 1e-2])

    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=[output1,output2])

    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
                    loss={'O1Err':'mae','O2Err':'mae'},
                    metrics={'O1Err':'mae','O2Err':'mae'})

    return model

tuner = kt.Hyperband(model_builder,
                     objective='val_loss',
                    max_epochs=100,
                    factor=3)

stop_early = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)
save = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('model.keras', save_best_only=True,mode='auto',monitor='val_loss')

tuner.search(X,(y1,y2),epochs=100,validation_split=0.2,callbacks=[stop_early])

As you can see, I've added a print in the model building step to print out the number of LSTM and dense layers in my model.
However, on running the code, I get a different number of layers appearing to what is expected, e.g.,
Search: Running Trial #3

Value             |Best Value So Far |Hyperparameter
1                 |1                 |num_LSTM_layers
240               |144               |lstm0_units
3                 |1                 |num_dense_layers
96                |16                |dense0_units
leaky_relu        |leaky_relu        |dense0_activation
0.001             |0.01              |learning_rate
144               |96                |lstm1_units
224               |192               |lstm2_units
96                |16                |dense1_units
relu              |leaky_relu        |dense1_activation
2                 |2                 |tuner/epochs
0                 |0                 |tuner/initial_epoch
4                 |4                 |tuner/bracket
0                 |0                 |tuner/round

l: 0
d: 0
d: 1
d: 2

As you can see, there should be 3 dense layers, but the tuner only displays the parameter for 1 dense layer. It looks like the tuner is "one step behind", for my previous trial, I had 2 LSTMs and 2 dense layer, and if I let it keep running, the next trial will have parameters for 3 dense layers and 1 LSTM layer.
I just can't work out what's causing this behaviour... any thoughts or suggestions are very much appreciated.
